How to make React google charts responsive
I can't make the charts responsive at all, at first they look as I want, but then they change the height after changing the data. I'm using tailwind. The grid doesn't behave as I want. After changing data in other component redux data is changed and selectedCityIndex is changed and useEffect is looking for that index.


const selectedCityIndex = useStoreSelector((state) => state.ui.selectedCity);
  const loadedData = useLoaderData() as forecastCityState;
  const maxTempsData = useStoreSelector((state) => state.forecast.forecastData);

  // State for forecast data
  const [forecastData, setForecastData] = useState(loadedData.forecastData);

  // Effect to update forecast data when selectedCityIndex or maxTempsData changes

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedCityIndex !== 0) {
      setForecastData(maxTempsData);
    }
  }, [selectedCityIndex]);

  // Function to generate temperature data array
  const generateTemperatureDataArray = () => {
    return forecastData.maxTemp.map((data, index) => [
      `${getNextDays(index).getDate()}.${getNextDays(index).getMonth() + 1}.`,
      forecastData.minTemp[index],
      forecastData.maxTemp[index],
    ]);
  };

  // Function to generate wind data array
  const generateWindDataArray = () => {
    return forecastData.maxWind.map((data, index) => [
      `${getNextDays(index).getDate()}.${getNextDays(index).getMonth() + 1}.`,
      forecastData.maxWind[index],
    ]);
  };

  // Generate data arrays
  const temperatureDataArray = generateTemperatureDataArray();
  const windDataArray = generateWindDataArray();

  return (
    <div className="row-start-4 row-span-3 xl:row-span-3 col-start-1 col-end-8 flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-between w-full h-full gap-8">
      <Chart
        className="bg-white shadow-2xl rounded-2xl border-2 border-gray-50 "
        chartType="LineChart"
        data={[
          ["date", "min temp °C ", "max temp °C "],
          ...temperatureDataArray,
        ]}
        options={optionsTemperatureChart}
        width={"100%"}
        height={"100%"}
      />

      <Chart
        className="bg-white shadow-2xl rounded-2xl border-2 border-gray-50 h-full"
        chartType="LineChart"
        data={[["DATE", "wind speed in km/h"], ...windDataArray]}
        options={optionsWindChart}
        width={"100%"}
        height={"100%"}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Charts;

I want them to remain as they were at the beginning.
